# Collection of LogContext Properties

Tags: c#, logging, middleware, serilog, serilog-aspnetcore

How can I get collection of properties current LogContext in ASP.NET Core custom Middleware?
I push property in Middleware like this:

```
var profile = context.Request.Host.Host;

using (LogContext.PushProperty("TestProp", "MyCustomProp"))
using (LogContext.PushProperty("Profile", profile))
{
  await _next(context);
}
```

Then I want to get the whole collection of properties, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interface is deliberately designed not to surface such information - the information is purely for the use of `Enrich.FromLogContext` and subject to change. You can read [the impl](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/c5a5b44daf11d5be8add28b862103d949e1a16aa/src/Serilog/Context/LogContext.cs).

You'll thus need to manage this externally.

---

One thing that is supported common practice is to use `{Properties}` in your message template to render all the properties you added via:

```
.Enrich.FromLogContext() 
.WriteTo.Console("[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj} {Properties} {NewLine}{Exception})
```

Comment: sorry, on what do I call.Enrich ? where do I get context, I have only _logger and LogContext. How do I get result in StringBuilder. My case is string msg for user: "An error happened, please write request id to call support". Request id pushed to LogContext .. someshere else

Comment: `Enrich` is an extension method on `LoggerConfiguration`, i.e. you do it in your Composition Root in the host app. `context` in the above is a HTTP request context. I'd recommend asking a fresh question, as what you're asking is only partially related to this question or answer; be sure to include as much information as to what you've done, what you need to fit in with, and what you want the output to look like as you can so that someone will be able to help you getting to a good solution. Bottom line though is that you don't extract context from the logger to render as messages to the user